# Php5-gd error linux

Tags: linux, php, kali-linux

So i'm new to the whole server building stuff, and I am trying to make a DVWA server on Kali Linux, but it gives me an error which says:The PHP module PHP-GD is not installed. But when I try to run this command: **apt-get install php5-gd** it gives me an error saying: `Unable to locate package php5-gd.` I have tried to search online but no-one else seems to have this problem.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: check your php version. If it is 5.6 you need to run command apt-get install php5.6-gd

Comment: Use `apt-cache search php | grep gd` to find the correct package name to use for `apt-get`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have linux server then try

```
sudo yum install php-gd
```

For version specific

```
sudo yum install php55-gd
```

or

```
sudo yum install php56-gd
```

or

```
sudo yum install php70-gd
```

and then run

```
sudo service httpd restart
```